# parse output and style xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have xml located on a remote server with the following format:

```
<query_results>
    <row id="1">
        <distance>...</distance>
        <post_title>...</post_title>
        <post_excerpt>...</post_excerpt>
        <ID>...</ID>
    </row
    <row id="2">
    .........................etc
</query_results>
```

I need my javascript to go through each of these rows in a way so that I can append each to a div on my html document with a class for styling without the script caring too much what the individual names are for each element in each row. I have used Jquery's parse XML function, however i am lost after that. Anybody got a good idea how to do this? Any help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: In a DIV, as in HTML?

Comment: yes, exactly. to append the data to html in side of a div (so that it can be styled)

Comment: Ehm, wouldn't that be invalid HTML ?

Comment: im talking about putting text inside of a div for styling purposes. sorry if that wasn't clear. example: <div><p>stuff</p></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/4YCLf)** with a possible solution to your problem. It loads your sample XML from this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/11234909).

In the HTML there is a placeholder:

```
<div id="query_results"/>
```

You can load the file using JQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/url/to/your/file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parser
});
```

In the parser function you can use `.find()` and `.children()` to navigate the XML:

```
function parser(xml) {
    $(xml).find('query_results').children().each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var id  = row.attr("id");
        var rowContents = "";

        row.children().each(function() {
            var tag = $(this);
            var tagName = tag[0].tagName;
            rowContents += "<div class='"+tagName+"'>"+tag.text()+"</div>";
        });
        var newRow = "<div id='row"+id+"'>"+rowContents+"</div>";
        $("#query_results").append(newRow);
    }); 
}
```

I used the row IDs and names to create and ID for each row DIV, for example:

```
<div id="row1"> ... </div>
```

And then used the tag names inside each row as classes:

```
<div class="distance"> ... </div>
<div class="post_title"> ... </div>
```

The `parser()` function above builds the `divs` and adds them to the placeholder `div`. The final result will be:

```
<div id="query_results">
    <div id="row1">
        <div class="distance">...</div>
        <div class="post_title">...</div>
        <div class="post_excerpt">...</div>
        <div class="ID">...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2">...</div>
</div>
```

Then you can style the result in CSS using selectors such as:

```
#query_results div { ... }
#query_results div div { ... }
#row1 .distance { ... }
#row2 .ID { ... }
```